# Version of Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

It is easy to show that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\int_0^\frac{1}{n} x~\mathrm{d}x.
$$
I was wondering whether given $g \in C(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$, it also holds that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\int_{\left \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \leq g(x) \leq \frac{1}{n} \right \rbrace} g(x)~\mathrm{d}x = g(0)
$$
We can assume that $\left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) = 0 \right \rbrace$ has finite measure.

I tried to substitute $g(x) = y$ but since I do not know the structure of $g$, this does not help a lot. I know it looks a lot like Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, but I do not know any version that I can apply. Any help/reference or hint is appreciated. I would also be happy if you could tell me if there is another class of functions $g$ for which this holds.

Comment: You didn't state the first result correctly (should be $=0$ on the right). The second result fails since $g(0)$ need not be $0.$ This problem doen't have much to do with the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: Right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Take
$$
g(x) = \min(1, \frac1{x^2}).
$$
Then the integral in question is equal to
$$
2n \int_{\sqrt n}^\infty \frac1{x^2} dx = 2n \frac1{\sqrt n} \to\infty.
$$
The limit has nothing to do with Lebesgue differentiation. It is more a question on how much mass of $g$ is on sets, where $g$ is small.

Comment: That ist what i expected. Thank you